# ASP.NET Core with Entity Framework - code first migrations aren't reading my environment variables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 2 Web API using Entity Framework code first. My `DbContext` is not in the same assembly as the API itself so to allow me to use the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet` tooling I've added an implementation of `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>` to the `DbContext`'s project:

```
public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>
{
    private static IConfiguration _configuration;

    public static IConfiguration Configuration
    {
        get
        {
            if (_configuration != null) return _configuration;

            _configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{EnvName ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            return _configuration;
        }
    }

    public MyDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnString");
        var migrationsAssembly = typeof(MyDbContext).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

        return new MyDbContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

I don't have an `appsettings.json` in this project, but I have added a system environment variable with the name `ConnectionStrings:MyConnString` and the value of my connection string.

When I run a tooling command such as `dotnet ef migrations add "Whatever"` then I get an error saying connection string cannot be null. So I guess the configuration builder is not reading my environment variable. If I replace the variable `connectionString` with a hard-coded connection string it works fine.

Can anyone tell me how to get this working? Is there an alternative to using environment variables perhaps which still keeps my connection string secret? As far as I'm aware, user secrets can only be used with web projects.

Comment: Can you post the Configuration file where your connection string is stored?

Comment: There isn't one. Like I said, the connection string is in my environment variables. My API project has an appsettings.json which starts with `{ "ConnectionStrings": { "MyConnString": "***" } }` but I'm not sure how this is relevant to my question...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` is, as the name implies, only for *development*. It doesn't support, or really have any concept of, environments. It's simply a way to run migrations against a class library, which because it's not a startup project, has no way to actually have the `DbContext` injected in.

Long and short, the docs hard-code the connection string for a reason. There's no reason to *not* hard-code it as it can only ever be that one connection string that's used.

Comment: Thanks. What you say makes sense, but since the implementation of `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` has to be a class within the codebase, there's always a chance of the hard-coded connection string winding up in source control. Sure it's only going to be a local dev connection but still it goes against good principles and I'd argue _is_ a reason to not hard code. But I'll defer to your fine SO reputation :)

Comment: There's no need for that. I can be as wrong as anyone else. SO rep is mostly a function of time. What I or anyone posts here is *guidance*, and you should always take it for what it's worth. As far as the connection string goes, you can externalize if you want. Your argument there is valid. The important part is that you can't switch it out based on environment.